Javascript JSON parser in PureData
I'm trying to create a JSON script with retrieve, parse, and get functions as an object in PureData using the pdjs external. The pdjs external uses Google's V8 JavaScript engine. I'm able to parse built in JSON just fine, but not when it's JSON retrieved from the web. Where am I going wrong? Is my async function not correct?
Here is my code - both files should be in the same folder and pdjs should be installed in PureData.
Javascript (saved as (js-jsonparser.js'):
// Number of inlets and outlets for the Puredata object
inlets = 1;
outlets = 1;


// JSON object
const obj = {};

// To test
const json = JSON.parse('{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');


async function getjson(url)
{
    // Wait on the fetching of the JSON
    obj = await (await fetch(url).json());

    // Return the JSON object
    return obj;
}

function load()
{
    // Retrieve the passed url
    let url = arguments[0];

    // Define result variable
    let result;

    // if an argument was passed
    if (url)
    {
        // Call the getjson async function to retrieve the json
        let g = getjson(url);

        // Send 'retrieved' out the outlet
        g.then(result = "retrieved");
        g.then(outlet(0, result));

    }
    else
    {
        // Send 'error' out the outlet
        result = "error";
        outlet(0, result)
    }

    // to test via the pd window
    //post(result);
}

function get()
{
    // Send retrieved value out the outlet
    outlet(0, json.name); // this works with my 'built in' JSON
    outlet(0, obj.url); // this does not work with the retrieved JSON
}

Puredata patch (saved as jsonparser.pd):
#N canvas 427 166 1255 567 12;
#X declare -lib pdjs;
#X obj 264 180 l2s;
#X msg 296 136 compile;
#X text 351 134 recompile source;
#X obj 264 115 t a b;
#X obj 262 212 print;
#X msg 117 36 load https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date=2024-06-06
;
#X msg 294 86 get url;
#X obj 504 -5 declare -lib pdjs;
#X obj 264 159 js js-jsonparser.js;
#X connect 0 0 4 0;
#X connect 1 0 8 0;
#X connect 3 0 8 0;
#X connect 3 1 1 0;
#X connect 5 0 3 0;
#X connect 6 0 3 0;
#X connect 8 0 0 0;


The way you are calling .json() looks wrong, you should either do
obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();

or
obj = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())

Update: even better split this into two lines, and also make sure the request was succesful.
const response = await fetch(url)

if (!response.ok) {
   console.warn("request failed: ", response.status)
   return
}

const json = await response.json()


It's even simpler if you split it up. res = await fetch(url); obj = await res.json();. The point of using await is to allow writing async code that looks sequential.

@Barmar yeah good point, just updated.

I've put the following into my getjson() function post("request made"); const response = await (await fetch(url)); if (!response.ok) { post("request failed"); return; } if (response.ok) post("request success"); const json = await response.json(); and it does not work in Puredata. Added post() outputs along the way to see where it goes wrong and it seems to be the const response = await (await fetch(url)) line. The same code in a browser (post() replaced with console.log()) works just fine. I've tested another async function in Puredata minus the fetch() and that works.

@garrettlynchirl I'm not familiar with Puredata, but it's possible fetch is not supported. You should also wrap the calling function in a try / catch block to catch any errors that may be thrown
